# regex: allow all except number length

Tags: regex, logstash

I need to parse a string like this:

```
ferf;:!:wo%ioz$\/r+fio)=13 ('".&3zf 691081886
```

and take all the characters but not the numbers at the end where the count of digits is 5 or higher.

I want all (include the space) except the 691081886, the length number is 5 minimum and the length of the preceding text is not more 4.

I try something like this:

```
(.+)[^0-9]{5,}
```

more explications:

i have a string with special characters and with a number length that is from minimum 5
I want get the string but not the numbers
In input i have this

```
my string with special characters and number
```

And output i want :

```
 my string with special characters
```

With real code
input:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0  691081886
```

output:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
```

Thanks

Comment: it is hard to visualize your question... do you think you could give some examples of expected inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Yes of course sorry: In output i want this

    ferf;:!:wo%ioz$\/r+fio)=13 ('".&3zf

i mean all except 691081886 that had a 5 number minimum length {5,}

Comment: what about something like (.*?)\d+$  assuming that the number you do not want is at the end of the string?

Comment: @user3680350, user3334690 is right with one minor adjustment since you want minimum 5: `(.*?)\d+{5,}$`

Comment: I try it but it doesn't works, i need the complete string in output except  691081886 If someone know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is always a number at the end of the string, you could use

```
.*(?=\b\d{5,}$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
.*      # Match as many characters as possible
(?=     # until the following regex can be matched:
 \b     # Start of a number (or other alphanumeric "word")
 \d{5,} # At least five digits
 $      # until the end of the string
)       # End of lookahead
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.+?)\s*\d{5,}$
```

See [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aS1qR5).

I believe this is what you're after.  If you can guarantee at least one space as a delimiter between your desired string and the final number you're discarding, you can change the `*` to `+` on the \s.